# Save PeakExpiratoryFlowRate HealthKit record

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

I am trying to record a 3 digit NSNumber to health kit as a PeakExpiratoryFlowRate, the code is below

```
- (void)PeakFlowupdate:(NSNumber *)pkFlow
{

    NSString *identifier = HKQuantityTypeIdentifierPeakExpiratoryFlowRate;
    HKQuantityType *peakFlowType = [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:identifier];

    HKQuantity *myPeakFlow = [HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit minuteUnit] doubleValue:[pkFlow doubleValue]];
    HKQuantitySample *peakFlowSample = [HKQuantitySample quantitySampleWithType:peakFlowType quantity:myPeakFlow startDate:[NSDate date] endDate:[NSDate date]];

    [healthStore saveObject:peakFlowSample withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"SAVED!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }

    }];
}
```

However I am receiving this error when I try to save the data to health kit

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   '_HKObjectValidationFailureException', reason: 'HKQuantitySample 250
>   min 2016-06-22 10:32:24 +1200 2016-06-22 10:32:24 +1200 requires unit
>   of type Volume/Time. Incompatible unit: min

Answer (score 0):

As the message of the exception states, you cannot instantiate a peak flow sample with a quantity specified in minutes. Peak flow is measured in units of Volume/Time, so you'll need to use something like `[[HKUnit literUnit] unitDividedByUnit:[HKUnit minuteUnit]]`.